# How to insert text with stroke using python image library

Tags: python, python-imaging-library

```
draw.text((60,270), 'HELLO', fill='white', font=font)
```

This is my code which only inserts the word 'HELLO' in white.
I want to insert the text, filled with the white color and has a stroke in black.

Answer (score 0):

Draw the text several times with your stroke color with an offset, then finally once more with your fill color:

```py
def stroke_text(draw, font, text, x, y, stroke_size, stroke_color, fill_color):
    for xo in range(-stroke_size, stroke_size + 1):
        for yo in range(-stroke_size, stroke_size + 1):
            if xo == yo == 0:
                continue
            draw.text((x + xo, y + yo), text, fill=stroke_color, font=font)
    draw.text((x, y), text, fill=fill_color, font=font)

stroke_text(draw, font, 'HELLO', 60, 270, 3, 'red', 'white')
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this code will help you. Color code in RGB

```
draw.text((1850, 700), text, stroke_width=10, stroke_fill=(0, 0, 0), font=myFont, fill=(255 , 255 , 255))
```

or

```
draw.text((1850, 700), text, stroke_width=10, stroke_fill='black', font=myFont, fill='white')
```